# Force display of 'title' attribute of element and keep visible until further notice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I want to use the title attribute to store my validation message in. I am currently using ketchup, for our validation library. We have tried other plugins, but like ketchup's functionality. I want to trigger the error, and display the title attribute until the error is corrected. Is there a way to keep the title attribute open, on an element, even when the user leaves the element, until the validation is corrected.

Comment: That's usually called a "tool tip". There are plug-ins for that already.

Comment: css's :after {content: attr(title); } can do the trick...

Comment: There is no way to force things in JavaScript, since JavaScript can be disabled. But if you want something to be displayed when JavaScript is enabled, just make your JavaScript code add it to document content. If you have problem with this, please show the code you’ve tried. In general, using the `title` attribute for a validation message is a wrong approach and violates HTML specificatrions.

Comment: We do not want to use Qtip, Tooltip plugins, and such. Our entire application runs off of jsViews, and is internal. I am aware of these plugins, as we are using ketchup, but we need the display message and functionality to be different. That is where the question stems from. I do not want to dynamically append a container to display it, as our set up with inputs are sometimes grids, and will jack with styling. Sometimes, it does plug an play to use what is already out there. So i need to find a way to do it in an alternative way. Maybe I could put the tip in a que, until triggered.....

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: actually, you ARE supposed to use title for validation messages. that where the validation error message gets its text after all...

Comment: I understand your answers, and appreciate the speedy response. Just trying to think of a way to handle it in this manner, not a way to handle it with another method. Please respond to the question asked. If I cannot display a tooltip/title value, without having to trigger hover,focus, etc, then maybe that is the answer I am looking for. Another route...  Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @Leighton, no answer has been given, just comments. There is no well-defined *question*.

Comment: Good conversation on such a simple topic. Thanks everyone, and that is what I mean. There are different methods to get things done. Funny, when you do everything by the "rules", creation gets thrown out.

Comment: @dandavis, check HTML specifications. Software that uses `title` for validation messages is non-conforming, and such an approach messes things up (partly because `title` attribute values are shown or spoken to users even when no validation has been carried out).

Comment: I corrected the question to make it a little clear. BTW. I come here for help, and helping. Not for status gaining on the political do's and don'ts that stack says are efficient and not. Thanks again.                   @dandavis  --->  Thanks! That is what I meant. Even if this is completely wrong for a reason, not just for the norm's of how to do it, that would be an answer. Thanks, so I will use a different route.   Though, I would clear out the title attribute if there was no error, or if it was corrected. We do not use the title attribute for anything else.So this does not interrupt us.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: i did check the spec. html5 says title is "Advisory information associated with the element.", not terribly specific, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation explains how the title works in html5 validation. also, ATs should alter the title presentation when pattern is present.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't control the browser's tooltip handling. You will need to use some other method to display the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the tooltip is not working here but I've tested it's working fine.

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
  if($("#name").val().length < 3) {
    
    $("#name").tooltip('show');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  title="Your name" id="name">
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I think you got mixed up with the HTML tooltip (title="something"), and bootstraps tooptip, which needs attributes in the html tag, e.g. <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Hover</a>

Comment: I am working on a template which has various libraries already included so I don't know what made my code work fine there @LeoMuller